# How to add a rewrite rule to remove paramaters in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

How would I change 
site.com/blog/article.php?title=mystory to site.com/blog/article/mystory ?

I am completely new to .htaccess so haven't attempted anything as yet.

Comment: It doesn't have multiple paramaters

Comment: That does not matter. If you look at the answer, it only uses the parameter `title`.